# Use PHP to encode rich text (html) to a single string

Tags: php, html, exec

Member [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/822053/chris) pointed out an issue for [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903691/using-exec-in-php-passing-arguments) where passing strings via exec() need special treatment to avoid spaces.

```
<?php
{
$ID = $_POST["ID"];
$RICHTEXT = $_POST["RICHTEXT"];
exec ("/usr/local/bin/php /home/admin/folder1/TESTS/process_it.php $ID $RICHTEXT >/dev/null &");
}
?>
```

Assuming $RICHTEXT is a page of html, how can $RICHTEXT be encoded to a single string that will work with exec()?

I have tried to replace all the white spaces with &nbsp; and it fails. I have also applied htmlentities and it fails. Any ideas?

Comment: I can't resist asking what you're doing passing text through the standard input of a php script *from a php script*. Is there some reason why you can't just include the php script and give it the input directly? Also, please tell me you're not really executing user input ;_;

Comment: This is the distilled version of the issue. The issue being that after using http POST, the processing of the posted data takes a long time. So rather than wait for the http response, I send the data to be processed to another php script.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138374/close-a-connection-early) for the answer to your problem. At *least* write your $richtext and $id to a temporary file and pipe them into standard input instead of just pasting them right on the command line :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use [escapeshellarg](http://www.php.net/escapeshellarg)()

Something like:

```
exec (sprintf("/usr/local/bin/php /home/admin/folder1/TESTS/process_it.php %s %s >/dev/null &", escapeshellarg($ID), escapeshellarg($RICHTEXT)));
```